# how to draw a slanting line in blackberry using Graphics class

Tags: blackberry

I want to know,how to draw the slanting line with thickness using  the graphics.Any ideas how to achieve this?

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`drawLine()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#drawLine%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method will draw a straight line in any direction, including on a "slant."  If you want the line to be thicker than a single pixel, then simply call `drawLine()` multiple times, adjusting the start and end points.  So for example, to draw a horizontal line that is two pixels thick:

```
g.drawLine(10, 10, 110, 10);
g.drawLine(10, 11, 110, 11);
```

Comment: i drawed using this option also,i am getting the blurred image,any  ideas apart from it.

Comment: Your line looks blurry?  That is probably due to anti-aliasing.  You can turn this off with `g.setDrawingStyle(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_AALINES, false);`

Comment: I tried that too,It was not effective,Any ideas apart from it.

Comment: sorry, not sure.  my lines always look crispy when AALINES is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to draw a rectangle:

```
int[] xPts = { 20, 40, 240, 220 };
int[] yPts = { 40, 20, 220, 240 };
graphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
graphics.drawFilledPath(xPts, yPts, null, null);
```